# Cfdocument pdf reloaded into IE window becomes blank

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdocument

I have some buttons to generate PDF files inline in the browser.

The buttons will open a new window the first time and generate the PDF correctly.

However, if you click on any other button to generate the PDF file, which reloads the 2nd browser window, it becomes blank in IE.  It however works in Google Chrome.

Here are my two buttons

```
<form target="blank" action="create_label.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="Doe, John" name="full_name">
<input type="hidden" value="11 Test Ave" name="street_line1">
<input type="hidden" value="Testville, CA 00123" name="street_line3">
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="submit">

<form target="blank" action="create_label.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="Doe, Jane" name="full_name">
<input type="hidden" value="12 Test Ave" name="street_line1">
<input type="hidden" value="Testville, CA 00123" name="street_line3">
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="submit">
```

As you can see each button sends address info to create_label.cfm

The first time you click a button, it opens the blank window and loads the form data in pdf.

If I then go back and click either button again, the window will update and then become blank. Only in IE though. If i do this in Chrome it actually updates the pdf with the correct address.

Here is the create_label.cfm code

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="no" marginTop=".1" marginLeft=".1" marginRight=".1" marginBottom=".1" pageType="custom" pageWidth="2.625" pageHeight="2.0" overwrite="true"> 
<table width="225px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
<cfoutput>
<cfif isDefined('form.full_name')>
   <span style = "font-size:12px">#form.full_name#</span><br />
   </cfif>
   <cfif isDefined('form.street_line1')>
   <span style = "font-size:12px">#form.street_line1#</span><br />
   </cfif>
   <cfif isDefined('form.street_line2')>
    <span style = "font-size:12px">#form.street_line2#</span><br /> 
    </cfif>
    <cfif isDefined('form.street_line3')>
    <span style = "font-size:12px">#form.street_line3#</span><br /> 
    </cfif>
    <cfif isDefined('form.street_line4')>
    <span style = "font-size:12px">#form.street_line4#</span><br /> 
    </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
        </table>
        </cfdocument>
```

Any ideas why IE would not allow this? Is it caching something between IE and Adobe?

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes only, in create_lable.cfm replace the cfdocument tags with html tags and see if it affects the behaviour.  Also, put an underscore in front of the word blank in your cfform tags to see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: If i do _blank, then yes, it does, as each button then opens a brand new window, which I do not want to happen. I want just one new window to open and then each subsequent click to load in that 2nd window.

Comment: @Dan, If I just output HTML it works 100% fine. even outputting plain/text works fine.  It only doesn't work using PDF in IE.

Comment: I believe it is a caching 'issue' with IE. Try appending some unique value to the url and see if it works.  Something like `<form target="blank" action="create_label.cfm?<cfoutput>#CreateUUID()#</cfoutput>" method="post">`.  This should force IE to fetch the page again.

Comment: Miguel,

I actually did this and used create_label.cfm?id=1, id=2, etc.

It still shows up blank on the 2nd load and beyond.

It is really a weird issue I've never encountered before.

Comment: When the page shows up blank is the request actually hitting your ColdFusion page?  Use Fiddler (or something similar) to monitor the http traffic when you are requesting that page from IE.  That will tell you if it is a caching issue or not.

Comment: If i make create_label output Text or HTML or do a cfdump it does hit the CF server and the data is being passed. As soon as I make it a PDF document, it comes back blank on the 2nd load.  I will look at Fiddler, never used it before.

Comment: Are you setting any of the caching headers in your response?  You could try setting these to see if it makes a difference.  I usually use these three `<cfheader name="PRAGMA" value="NO-CACHE" />  <cfheader name="CACHE-CONTROL" value="NO-CACHE" />  <cfheader name="EXPIRES" value="-1" />`

Comment: @Miguel-F, tried the Cache headers, makes no difference. I installed Fiddler but when the new window opens, Fiddler does not register any new traffic. Not sure how to conf Fiddler to see the popups?

Comment: @Miguel-F got it working (Fiddler) and I maybe on to something. The first Label generated is using "post" all the rest of the labels after are using "GET". I don't know why, all of my print buttons are `<form  method="post" action="create_label.cfm?id#loop_counter#" target="blank">`

Comment: Cannot figure out why this is happening. The first "print label" which loads a new window uses "POST" according to Fiddler, Any subsequent "print label" then is using "GET" according to Fiddler. My code for the form is to use "POST" , how can this happen?